# Derivative of an inverse mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, inverse

Let $F: U\to V$ be a $C^1$invertible map and $G: U\to V$ it's its inverse, Then how can I find the derivative of $G$?

I tried this, Let $X\in U$, then $G○F=I$ the identity, and since $I$ is linear, we get $I'(X)=I$, so if we use the chain rule we get $$I=(G○F)'(X)=G'(F(X))○F'(X)$$

what should I do now?

Comment: Do you know the inverse function theorem?

Comment: yes i know it @Vercassivelaunos

Comment: The inverse function theorem is literally the answer to your question. The derivative of $G$ at $F(X)$ is the inverse of the derivative of $F$ at $X$.

Comment: And similarly, 
\begin{align}
I= D(F\circ G)_{F(x)}=DF_{G(F(x))}\circ DG_{F(x)}=DF_x\circ DG_{F(x)}
\end{align}
In other words, you have that $DF_x\circ DG_{F(x)}$ and $DG_{F(x)}\circ DF_x$ are the identities on the respective spaces. Therefore, by writing $y=F(x)$ or equivalently $x=F^{-1}(y)$, what is $DG_{y}=$?